# Changed values of collection not reflected in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js-collections

When i click on submit button i can't see the changes made to collection although on every click of checkbox change event is fired

```
//Model

    Wine = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Toggle the `IsSelected` state of this todo item.
        toggle: function () {
            debugger;
            this.save({
                IsSelected: !this.get('IsSelected')
            });
        }

    });
//Collection

    WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Wine,
        url: "http://localhost/Industries/data/data.json"

    });
```

//This is a list view collection and individual List item and here we bind the click event of checkbox and in Submit button here we check the the changed values

```
    WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#wineList'),
        initialize: function () {
            alert($('#divBtnSubmit'));
            wineList.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            wineList.each(function (wine) {
                $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({ model: wine }).render().el);
            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });
//Submit button

    WinedivBtnSubmit = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#divBtnSubmit'),
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {

            // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
            var template = _.template($("#save-div").html(), {});
            this.$el.append(template);
        },
        events: {
            "click #divBtnSubmit1": "saveWine"
        },
        saveWine: function () {
            debugger;
            wineList.each(function (wine) {
                alert(wine.get('ID') + '<<>>' + wine.get('IsSelected'));
            });
            return false;
            // alert(this.modelmodels);
        }
    });
//Indiviual list item



     WineListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: "li",
            template: _.template($('#wine-list-item').html()),
            initialize: function () {
            },
            events:
            {
                'click .toggle': 'toggleVisible'
            },
            toggleVisible: function () {
                this.model.toggle();
            },
            render: function (eventName) {
                $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });




    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "list",
            "wines/:id": "wineDetails"
        },
        initialize: function () {

        },

        list: function () {
           // this.wineList = new WineCollection();
            this.wineListView = new WineListView();
            this.btn = new WinedivBtnSubmit();
          //  wineList.fetch();
        },

        wineDetails: function (id) {
            this.wine = this.wineList.get(id);
            this.wineView = new WineView({ model: this.wine });
            this.wineView.render();
        }
    });



        wineList = new WineCollection();
        wineList.fetch();
    // on every click of checkbox this event is fired
        wineList.bind("change", function () {
            alert('list changed');
        });
        var app = new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
```